# pyspark isin multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Coming from pandas to pyspark I understand that you can substitute `isin` by `.join` with `how='inner'` or `how='left_anti`. This works for me in simple conditions but I cannot figure how to use it in more nuanced cases.

I have a case when I want to filter one dataframe by columns of several other dataframes, how can I do this ?

In pandas I would do:

```
df.loc[(df.A.isin(df2.A2)) & (df.B.isin(df3.B3), 'new_col'] = value
```

My pyspark attempt was

```
df = df.withColumn('new_col',
  when(
    (df.A.isin(df2.A2)) & (df.B.isin(df3.B3),
    value
  )
)
```

This fails with `AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) A2 missing from A,B ...` 
My guess is that I can use `isin` between columns of the same dataframe but cannot pass other dataframe columns to it.

EDIT:
my second attempt is definetely working but does not look opimal when I consider multiple such "isin-join-alternatives":

```
# split main frame into subframes
df1_notin = main_df.join(F.broadcast(df1), on='A', how='left_anti')
df1_isin = main_df.join(F.broadcast(df1), on='A', how='inner')
df2_notin_all = df1_notin.join(F.broadcast(df2), on='B', how='left_anti')
df2_isin = df1_notin.join(F.broadcast(df2), on='B', how='inner')
# conditionally fill with Bool values in my case
df2_notin_all = df2_notin_all.withColumn('new_column', F.lit(None).cast(BooleanType()))
df1_isin = df1_isin.withColumn('new_column', F.lit(True).cast(BooleanType()))
df2_isin = df2_isin.withColumn('new_column', F.lit(True).cast(BooleanType()))
main_df = df2_notin_all.unionByName(df1_isin).unionByName(df2_isin)
```

Comment: Have you tried `join` with `right_outer`? Like this `df.join(df2, on=df.a1==df2.b, how='right_outer').join(df3, on=df.a2==df3.c, how='right_outer')`. Then, the column of the main dataframe will contain `null` values, so the join dataframe can be filtered to get the desired output. And I think your assumption of the error is true.

Comment: Hmm, I get this but it will have entries from right frames I do not need. Those frames df2 and df3 I only need as filtering columns to know when to fill values in main df